# CSS3 and HTML5 in IE7 and 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, canvas

I have bootstrap and HTML5 elements like canvas on a webpage I am designing.
My client has asked me to provide support for IE browsers. I tried adding CSS3PIE, html5shiv, respondjs and excanvas to my project but IE8 still isn't showing the correct layout and the border radius and canvas elements doesn't work either.

Here is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>

        <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="js/excanvas.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css">
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">


</head>
```

I am using the code from this gist to apply the PIE.htc to the bootstrap classes:https://gist.github.com/coliff/5618329 (ie.css)

```
.img-circle{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.img-rounded{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.img-thumbnail{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.table-bordered{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
select,textarea,input,code,pre,kbd,pre{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.input-group-addon{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.btn{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.dropdown-menu{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.form-control{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.panel{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.well{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.nav-tabs > li > a{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.nav-pills > li > a{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.navbar{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.navbar-nav > li > a{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.navbar-toggle{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.breadcrumb{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.pagination{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.pager li > a,.pager li > span{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.modal-content{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.tooltip-inner{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.popover{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.popover-title{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.alert{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.thumbnail,.img-thumbnail{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.label{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.badge{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.progress{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.carousel-indicators li{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
.jumbotron{behavior:url(/scripts/PIE.htc)}
```

I also tried using absolute URLs to the PIE.htc file.

But the javascript isn't working and neither is any of the css3 features.
Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you *really* need to care about IE7?! With "IE Browsers" I'd assume IE9+ unless stated otherwise and paid with a decent amount of additional money.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I am not so concerned with IE7 but I really do need support for IE8

Comment: IE needs to be 11+ to be taken *care* of ;)

Comment: @abhitalks I need atleast the canvas and rounded corners working for IE8 actually.

Comment: Several good plugins were available to let IE<9 use canvas: ExCanvas, FlashCanvas & perhaps the best canvas plugin: Google Chrome Frame.  Since IE<9 has very little browser market share today, these plugins have deprecated. You might try tracking down a copy of Google Chrome Frame(?). My company's policy for clients requesting canvas support for IE<9 is to politely **but firmly** tell clients we will offer static versions of canvas pages along with a suggestion on that page which tells the user to update their browser to get the best experience.

Comment: @markE Thanks, I did manage to get it working in IE8 using flash canvas. The thing is that it is an animation, so a static image in IE is basically not really pleasing. I decided not to support IE7, as the performance in IE8 is not really good.

Answer (score 0):

Old IE's Use Depricated css Properties . You can use them in your css .
for some properties such as Animation , Transitions and all ... you can use `-ms-` before the property . for example : ` element { transition:all 2s; -ms-transition:all 2s; }

I hope it helps .